# Optimization algorithms

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have a sorting/division algorithm problem… Any CS ninja here?

I am building an app that divides tasks between members. Each task has a difficulty “score”. The tasks have to be divided as fairly as possible between an undefined number of members (this is the priority).
On top of this, each member can have personal preferences that remove / add  50%  of the « perceived painfulness » of a task.
For example, we could have:

```
all_tasks = {task1: 75, task2: 30, task3: 42, task4: 22, task5: 61, task6: 10, task7: 32, task8: 39}
member_preferences = {
    bob: {
        like: [task2, task5], 
        dislike: [task1, task7, task8]}, 
    joe: {
        like: [task3, task5, task7], 
        dislike: [task2, task6, task8]},
...
}
```

Any idea as to how to find the optimal allocation of tasks for everybody? Thanks!

Comment: remove the emoji tags, they don't resolve on StackOverflow, format the question for better readability (I'd do it myself but I don't want to remove something important) . It would make it way easier and less overwhelming to read

Comment: Will do, thanks for the format tips: first post here!

Comment: A Mixed Integer Programming (MIP) model will allow you to model this and experiment with different objectives.

Answer (score 3):

Just did some quick Wiki research. Seems like the problem you're describing is known as the [Fair Item Assessment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_item_assignment) problem. It's described as:

> The items have to be divided among several partners who value them differently, and each item has to be given as a whole to a single person.

It's slightly different, because the difficulty score is opposite of the value of a task. It's actually how much a person **doesn't** want the task, as opposed to how much they do. I'd imagine that you can easily work around this by negating the difficulty score. That way, a "bigger" value represents "easier" work.

Also, there are several definitions of "fairness", as described in the wiki page. Sadly, all of them seem to be NP-hard.

I would imagine that you're looking for a global definition of fair, where the maximum difficulty score of the unluckiest member is minimized. The article refers to a paper that calls this scenario the "[Santa Claus Problem](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1132516.1132522)" and provides an approximate solution. Remember to negate the difficulty scores before plugging them in.

Edit: A protip for looking for papers blocked behind a paywall. You can try e-mailing the authors directly, and they'll be more than happy to give you a free copy of the paper. The payment almost always goes 100% towards the publisher, so authors usually give them away when asked.